# non booting behaviour in ubuntu VPS with empty logs

Tags: ubuntu, boot, logging

I have an issue today, I have an ubuntu VPS. On this VPS I have PLESK installed, and I'm running 4 websites.
One of the websites suddenly stopped working, then I rebooted the VPS through SSH. After that, the machine stopped, it rebooted but refused all the connections.
I can access a rescue system by the hosting company to scroll through the files, but there are no logs after the reboot.

I've had this before, and the hosting company claims to have not done anything, and it suddenly started working (2 times after contacting them).
Does anyone know what could be wrong or have tips to troubleshoot?

The only access I have to the files is using this rescue system, where I can only access all the files.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You'll really need to get help from your host, or find and give us more information.